# Azure Logic App - stored procedure results to email attachment CSV

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm fairly new to Logic Apps, and have one that I simply cant figure out. So I'm reaching out to you experts.

I have a stored procedure in an Azure SQL database. I use a Logic App to run the stored procedure which returns a dataset.

The next piece is where I fall over:

I need to grab the results, create a CSV (the number of rows an columns will vary), and email the CSV.
Any of you dont this before?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context as to what you have implemented already at this point? Do you need help with the logic app from a helicopter view or are you struggling with e.g. the database connection or the processing of the data (creating a CSV for instance)?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done any SQL LogicApp stuff.. but as I remember the SQL connectors return it in a JSON format, so you just need to create a CSV Table from the JSON returned... now the harder thing is going to be the dynamic columns.

If your not doing anything else to data in the logicapp this should be fine and save the CSV after that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the JSON in a datalake storage then read it from there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).